# Is there a mute function for all members?

Tags: circuit, circuit-sdk

We are using several chat applications with audio function. Is it possible to mute all members on circuit while talking on other chat application?

Comment: Your question in its current form has nothing to do with programming or software development. Hence it is off-topic for this site: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

If this question is related to the SDK, then you can achieve this by muting the incoming audio streams. If you are asking about the official Circuit web application, then this is not the right place to ask such questions.